# Selecting a link inside a class with jQuery when there are multiple uses of that class

Tags: jquery

I've been stuck on this code for 2 days now and I'm pretty sure it's relatively simple. Basically I created The Periodic Table of Elements to practice some HTML/CSS and then I decided to make it interactive with jQuery. All I want is to click on a element and a new window opens taking you to that Wikipedia site for that element. I've only input links into the far left row to get the code right first. The problem is that all of the elements have the same class "box" so when I select that with jQuery and get the link inside that, it returns all the links in the page because every element has that same "box" class. Any nudge in the right direction would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Here's the link.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
    <title> Periodic Table of Elements, in CSS! </title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> <!--Main StyleSheet -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <!-- Google Fonts --> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQUery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <section>
    <div id="menu"> The Periodic Table of Elements </div> 
        <div id="container">
        <div id="panelOne">
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen"> H </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium"> Li </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium"> Na </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium"> K </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubidium"> Rb </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesium"> Cs </a></div> 
            <div class="box"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francium"> Fr </a></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelTwo">
            <div class="box"> Be </div> 
            <div class="box"> Mg </div> 
            <div class="box"> Ca </div> 
            <div class="box"> Sr </div> 
            <div class="box"> Ba </div> 
            <div class="box"> Ra </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"> Sc </div> 
            <div class="box"> Y </div> 
            <div class="box"> X </div> 
            <div class="box"> X </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"> Ti </div> 
            <div class="box"> Zr </div> 
            <div class="box"> Hf </div> 
            <div class="box"> Rf </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"> V </div> 
            <div class="box"> Nb </div> 
            <div class="box"> Ta </div> 
            <div class="box"> Db </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"> Cr </div> 
            <div class="box"> Mo </div> 
            <div class="box"> W </div> 
            <div class="box"> Sg </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"> Mn </div> 
            <div class="box"> Tc </div> 
            <div class="box"> Re </div> 
            <div class="box"> Bh </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"> Fe </div> 
            <div class="box"> Ru </div> 
            <div class="box"> Os </div> 
            <div class="box"> Hs </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"> Co </div> 
            <div class="box"> Rh</div> 
            <div class="box"> Ir </div> 
            <div class="box"> Mt </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"> Ni </div> 
            <div class="box"> Pd </div> 
            <div class="box"> Pt </div> 
            <div class="box"> Ds </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"> Cu </div> 
            <div class="box">Ag </div> 
            <div class="box"> Au </div> 
            <div class="box"> Rg </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelThree">
            <div class="box"> Zn </div> 
            <div class="box"> Cd </div> 
            <div class="box"> Hg </div> 
            <div class="box"> Cn </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelTwo">
            <div class="box"> B </div> 
            <div class="box"> Al </div> 
            <div class="box"> Ga </div> 
            <div class="box"> In </div> 
            <div class="box"> Ti </div> 
            <div class="box"> Uut </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelTwo">
            <div class="box"> C </div> 
            <div class="box"> Si </div> 
            <div class="box"> Ge </div> 
            <div class="box"> Sn </div>
            <div class="box"> Rb </div> 
            <div class="box"> Fl </div>  
        </div>
        <div id="panelTwo">
            <div class="box">N </div> 
            <div class="box">P </div> 
            <div class="box">As </div> 
            <div class="box">Sb </div> 
            <div class="box"> Bi </div> 
            <div class="box"> Uup </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelTwo">
            <div class="box"> O </div> 
            <div class="box"> S </div> 
            <div class="box"> Se </div> 
            <div class="box"> Te </div> 
            <div class="box"> Po </div> 
            <div class="box"> Lv </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelTwo">
            <div class="box"> F </div> 
            <div class="box"> Cl </div> 
            <div class="box"> Br </div> 
            <div class="box"> I </div> 
            <div class="box"> At </div> 
            <div class="box"> Uus </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="panelOne">
            <div class="box"> He </div> 
            <div class="box"> Ne </div> 
            <div class="box"> Ar </div> 
            <div class="box"> Kr </div> 
            <div class="box"> Xe </div> 
            <div class="box"> Rn </div> 
            <div class="box"> Uuo </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
    <div id="lowerContainer">
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> La </div> 
            <div class="box"> Ac </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Ce </div> 
            <div class="box"> Th </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Pr </div> 
            <div class="box"> Pa </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Nd </div> 
            <div class="box"> U </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Pm </div> 
            <div class="box"> Np </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Sm </div> 
            <div class="box"> Pu </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Eu </div> 
            <div class="box"> Am </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Gd </div> 
            <div class="box"> Cm </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Tb </div> 
            <div class="box"> Bk </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Dy </div> 
            <div class="box"> Cf </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Ho </div> 
            <div class="box"> Es </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Er </div> 
            <div class="box"> Fm </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Tm </div> 
            <div class="box"> Md </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Yb </div> 
            <div class="box"> No </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="box"> Lu </div> 
            <div class="box"> Lr </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infoContainer">
            This is the information. 
    </div> 
    </section>  
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $ic = $('#infoContainer');  
var $this = $(this); 
$ic.hide(); 
$('.box').click(
    function(){
        var link = $this.find('a');
        var newLink = $(link).attr('href');
        window.open(link, 'window name', 'window settings');
        return false; 
    }
  ); //End box click
}); //End ready
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xAXyd/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this could work for you

```
var newLink = $(this).find('a').attr('href')
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! I don't have enough rep to upvote you but I really appreciate it. So simple, yet works perfect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you will always have the link directly inside the div, you can just modify your selector

```
$('.box a').click(function() {
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'window name', 'window settings');
    return false;
});
```